# exec command is not working in php script

Tags: java, php, exec

I have a java file and it will generate itunes report. I want to execute this within my php script. Im using the exec() function in php:it is working properly in linux.But not in windows.Am i missing anything?Any help will be appreciated.

```
exec("java Autoingestion ".'USERNAME'." '".'PASSWORD'."' ".'VENDORID'." ".'REPORT_TYPE'." ".'DATE_TYPE'." ".'REPORT_SUB_TYPE'." ".'2012-05-28'."",$output,$return);
```

Comment: Can you give a try using `shell_exec` command ? Also let us know if you getting anything in `$output` ?

Comment: The string concatenation looks a little iffy. Try to `echo` it before throwing it in `exec`, and make sure it does what you think it does.

Comment: You are escaping straight into another string, what is the point doing this? Are you using constant place holders or variables as placeholders?

Answer (score 1):

Check the result of the string concatenation. It looks a little iffy:

```
"java Autoingestion USERNAME 'PASSWORD' VENDORID REPORT_TYPE DATE_TYPE REPORT_SUB_TYPE 2012-05-28"
```

You are not using any variables, or anything else, so there is no reason to concatenate stuff.

Even if the capitalized parts are placeholders you do not have to concatenate. Just use variable interpolation:

```
$username = 'USERNAME';
$password = 'PASSWORD';
$exec = "java Autoingestion '{$username}', '{$password}', ...";
exec($exec);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to check for the script output (both on stdout and stderr).

Check also the environment variables you need to run the script.